# Shutter's --selection command line option is missing

Tags: command-line, shutter

In Karmic, shutter used to have a commandline option called `--selection`, which I've used in a hack to replace `gnome-screenshot` with the funcionality of shutter.

However, this option doesn't not exist anymore, but instead `--select` exists... the problem being, that `--select` will immediately open the shutter mainwindow, without allowing me to select anything. The contextmenu of shutter still has the 'Selection' option, which makes me wonder why the commandline option had been removed.

Is there a different way to toggle the Selection option in shutter from the commandline?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu/Shutter are you using? I am using the version in the 10.10 repositories and it has the `--selection` option.

Comment: @DoR: I'm using version "0.87 (beta) Rev.917"

Comment: I am using Shutter v0.85.1 and it's avaialable for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed a previously activated PPA for shutter, which appears to have an unstable  Beta version of Shutter. Works now.

Comment: @Jorge Castro Thanks for reminding me. When I've written this answer, the site didn't allow me to accept it, and I had to wait a while... looks like I forgot to accept it. :-)